# How do people go about creating their own programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, grammar, compiler-theory

At university I majored in compiler theory and grammars, so have a good background in this area (although a long time ago) and know that the creation of a compiler is an enormous major undertaking, at least for a language such as C++.

So I'm confused as to the large number of programming languages that seem to have been created by individuals as opposed to large groups of people working at a company. Ruby for example, according to Wikipedia it was created by one person  - I don't know the language perhaps it's incredibly simple, but my point is there are bucket loads of self-created languages out there.

So how does one go about creating their own language (which isn't too simple as to be pretty useless) as an individual and not spend one's entire life doing so?

Are there any good books on the subject (not on compilers and in general, spec)?

Comment: This question sounds like [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: who says it *doesn't* take an entire lifetime  to make a self-created language useful?

Answer (score 3):

> (although a long time ago) and know that the creation of a compiler is an enormous major undertaking, at least for a language such as C++.

A lot of things have conspired to make things easier:

1. **Computers have a lot more RAM and speed.** Much of the challenge of writing early compilers was being able to do so efficiently and with a minimum of memory. That's why C can compile in a single pass: at the time, you may not have had enough memory to even fit an entire source file in it. Where before a lot of the magic of compiler-writing was optimizing your symbol table representation and parsing as fast as physically possible, now you can get by doing things much simpler and easier.
2. **Base technology has gotten better.** Most languages have nice easy to use parser libraries, high-level data structures (symbol tables are a snap if you already have a nice hashtable implementation!) and other tools to make getting a compiler or interpreter up and running much easier.
3. **GC is ubiquitous.** Most new languages being created today are garbage collected. That makes it easier to design the language (you don't have to specify detailed memory semantics). At the same time, you can target some existing GC platform like the CLR or the JVM so as the language author, you don't have to write your own GC. In fact, targeting the CLR or JVM makes your job as a compiler writer much easier in general: as a higher-level platform, the bytecode meets you halfway.
4. **Most new languages are dynamically-typed.** The majority of new languages being created are dynamically typed. Those are *much* easier to design and implement. I've found that a majority of the challenge in language design is designing a type system. Likewise, compiling or interpreting a static language is more of a challenge. Dynamic languages where everything is just a property bag are surprisingly easy to get up and running.
5. **Again, computers have a lot more RAM and speed.** Back in the day, if your language was to have any chance of success, it needed to compile down to efficient machine code, use memory efficiently and run fast. Otherwise it would be unusably slow. Now that computers are so much faster, even a slow language like Ruby is still fast enough for many real uses. As a compiler writer you don't need as much optimization skill as you used to.

It's also worth noting that *no one* is making a new language as complex as C++ these days. C++ really is near the top end of language complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I have gone a little way down the route of creating my own language. I started off doing this to represent requirements, analysis and design constructs, rather than a code compiler. For this purpose even a very simple language can be useful. I found it valuable to be able to read and write such constructs in a very constrained version of English - template sentences mainly. Then it became useful to have the language machine readable and so I constructed lexers and parsers to read the language using Lex and Yacc. As I have gone I have expanded the language and its parsers to deal with the expansions.

I am aware that this is a very long way from a robust compiler for a language as extensive as C++, but illustrates one motivation for going down this route.  I would suggest that your view of simple languages as being pretty useless is an overstatement. Even a very limited language can be of substantial use.

Answer (score 0):

Though I have basically no experience in making languages of my own, I do have a good amount of experience learning new ones, so I could suggest this -

The programming industry is a marketplace of languages. Languages rise and fall in popularity based on their simplicity to learn and use, lack of commercial and legal restriction, applicability to real-life situations, flexibility, and power. If you want your language to be popular one day, try to go for these.

If you're designing a toy language for its own sake (as many computer scientists do), it's a interesting theoretical exercise and still quite valid, but you might not expect it to become quite as widespread.